# Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous on $E$, a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{1}$. Must $E$ be closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This question is inspired by Chapter 4 Exercise 8 from Baby Rudin, which presents the assumptions given in the title of this question, and then asks you to prove that $f$ is bounded. I've seen some other people's solutions, but I was thinking there might be a way to do this using the Heine-Borel theorem. The logic is as follows:

- $E$ is bounded by assumption. If we can show that it is also closed,
  then by Heine-Borel, it is compact.
- $f$ is uniformly continuous
  $\implies$ $f$ is continuous.
- Then $E$ is compact and $f$ is U.C., so $f$ must be bounded (Theorem 4.15).

Comment: Huh? How is $E$ compact?

Comment: Why do you think $E$ must be closed?

Comment: No, $E$ does not have to be closed, and it is easy to come up with examples where it is not. Fo example, any polynomial on an open interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: You need to try some basic stuff. $f=0$ on $(0,1)$

Comment: If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $E$, then isn't it uniformly continuous on every subset of $E$, whether open, closed, or neither?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If $f:X\to Y$ is uniformly continuous then its restriction to **any** subset of $X$ is uniformly continuous as well.

So, for example given $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$ is of course uniformly continuous. Then your $E$ can be any subset of $\mathbb{R}$, bounded if you wish, but definitely not necessarily closed.